# How to convert dictionary to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a dictionary to a dataframe for example
sample = {'alphabet': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'number': ['1', '2', '3']}

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| alphabet | A |
| alphabet | B |
| alphabet | C |
| number | 1 |
| number | 2 |
| number | 3 |

I used this
`df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=sample, orient='index')`
`df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)`

and the result i got was:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alphabet | A | B | C |
| number | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using comprehension to convert dict to list of tuples

```
import pandas as pd
data_dict = {'alphabet': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'number': ['1', '2', '3']}
data_list = [(key, i) for key, value in data_dict.items() for i in value]
print(data_list)  # [('alphabet', 'A'), ('alphabet', 'B'), ('alphabet', 'C'), ('number', '1'), ('number', '2'), ('number', '3')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=('Column A', 'Column B'))
print(df)
```

creates following DataFrame

```
   Column A Column B
0  alphabet        A
1  alphabet        B
2  alphabet        C
3    number        1
4    number        2
5    number        3
```

Answer (score 1):

i don know there are better way, but your problem can be solved with unpivot.

```
out = pd.DataFrame(sample).unstack().droplevel(-1)\
        .reset_index().set_axis(['colA', 'colB'], axis=1)
```

out:

```
    colA        colB
0   alphabet    A
1   alphabet    B
2   alphabet    C
3   number      1
4   number      2
5   number      3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) made from your (`sample`) dictionary :

```
pd.Series(sample).explode().to_frame("Column B").reset_index(names=["Column A"])
```

Output :

```
   Column A Column B
0  alphabet        A
1  alphabet        B
2  alphabet        C
3    number        1
4    number        2
5    number        3

# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use dict data with

> pd.DataFrame()

```
import pandas as pd
data_dict = {'alphabet': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'number': ['1', '2', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)#, columns=('Column A', 'Column B'))#
#df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, columns=('Column A', 'Column B'))if u want to change column name use this line
print(df)
```